# we need to add the sales condition between two dates, but the first date is the transactions from 7 am

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

i need sum amount   where trans time in first date >= 9:00 am 
when i write

```
select sum(amount)
from <table>
where (trans date between '25-10-2018 ' and '26-10-2018' ) and transtime >9am
```

not sum amount in 26 because time < the trans time i add it

need add time condition in first date only  like where (trans date ='25-10-2018 ' and  and transtime >9am  and  transdate between '25-10-2018 ' and '26-10-2018'

The idea is I have sales sold after 12 am this sales to 3 am followed the previous day 
we need to add the sales condition between two dates, but the first date is the transactions from 7 am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution:

```
select sum(amount)
from <table>
where 
   (transdate between '25-10-2018' and '26-10-2018') and 
   ((transtime > 9am AND transdate = '25-10-2018') OR 
    (transdate <> '25-10-2018'))
```

Second solution:

```
select sum(amount)
from <table>
where 
   (
    CAST(transdate AS DATETIME) + 
    CAST(transtime AS DATETIME)
   ) between '25-10-2018 09:00' and '26-10-2018'
```

There may be other solutions.
Each of these has it's pros and cons, so choose depending on your needs, model and indexes.